# Outlook office.js add-in On Send event for PC client - is it possible?

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins

As the title mentions, I've got a question regarding the possibility of implementing the on send event functionality on the outlook PC client.

I current got an add-in running that blocks sending emails on the outlook WEB variant properly and allows sending them when the criteria is met. I've used the examples the microsoft documentation provides to get it to work. This example however doesn't work on the outlook PC (windows) client. Other functionality works just fine on the outlook PC client, it's just the on send not functioning. All I get on the outlook PC client is the error "[add-in name] couldn't complete. Please try sending this message later" upon pressing send.

Been looking at this for the past few days and based on all the microsoft documentation it gives me the impression that it should be possible, but I can't find any examples online or anyone really verifying it either. Which bring us to my question as I mentioned at the start;

Is it possible to make the outlook on send event work on the outlook PC client as well? And if so, does anyone have an example of how to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue.
So to recap; when running the nodejs server locally, the on send didn't appear to work for the outlook pc client. (It did for outlook web)

What I did was put the code on an external server and ran the nodejs. Then I created an IIS website with https and redirecred it towards the localhost port of the nodejs server.

After doing this and installing the manifest through the URL the issue no longer persisted for the pc client and worked exactly the same as the outlook web variant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the on-send feature for Outlook add-ins is supported in certain versions of Outlook win-32. There is documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows#supported-clients-and-platforms) about which versions are supported and some [code examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows#code-examples).

Comment: Yes, I went through all of that but the issue on the outlook pc client persisted. However, I managed to find a fix. When running the nodejs server locally, for the onsend on the pc client it didn't work. But when I released the nodejs server to a server and redirected the localhost to a https url and installed the manifest through that link, the process went well on the outlook pc client. Maybe due to it trying to go through a http or lack or a certificate that this issue persisted? Anyway, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

I am new, so I cannot add comments - but keep in mind that if you plan to put your add-in into AppSource - the doc says it will be banned: you are not allowed to use the OnSend event for anything in there.

I hope this helps you avoid some pain if you had those plans!

"  Important.  Add-ins that use the on-send feature aren't allowed in AppSource. "
( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=classic )